# Read Global Event in world main script from isolated popup.js in chrome extention

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a chrome extention that reads event form external script and after receiving it from   main script i can't read it from isolated script.
Here

mainfest.js

```
  {
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Helper",
    "description": "helper test",
    "version": "0.1",
    "permissions": [
      "scripting",
      "activeTab",
      "tabs"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "world": "MAIN",
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ],"action":{
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
  }
```

content.js

```
window.helper = true;
window.arr_values = [];
document.addEventListener("custom_data", function(e) {
//This already been fired
   window.arr_values.push(e);

});
```

popup.js

```
// How can i read the arr_values from here
  async function getPageVar(name, tabId) {
    const [{result}] = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      func: name => window[name],
      args: [name],
      target: {
        tabId: tabId ??
          (await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}))[0].id
      },
      world: 'MAIN',
    });
    alert(result);
    return result;
  }

  (async () => {
    alert(await getPageVar('arr_values'));
    
  })();
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Helper</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-3" style="width: 450px;">
        <h2 class="text-center">Helper</h2>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="item"></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</html>
```

If that is not possible how can i access the `document.getElementById("item").innerHTML` from content.js which lives in main world of the page.

Comment: Your popup is an entirely different document, so you need to use executeScript as shown in [this answer](/a/46870005).

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for your response, it still can't read any variable event even the empty array ```arr_values``` with the same code you share earlier It returns null  ```alert(await getPageVar('arr_values'))```

Comment: Even the ```const [{result}] = await chrome.scripting.executeScript``` is reading null

Comment: Well I don't see your full code so I can only guess it's because `let` is lexically scoped. Try using `var` instead of `let` in your content.js or even `window.arr_values = []`. Don't forget to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page and the tab after editing.

Comment: @wOxxOm the above edit have every single line of code i had i double check your notes 
still had no luck and got double nulls from the two alerts in popup.js

Comment: Update: i managed to get ```[{},{},{}]``` this from the arr_values from this line ```await getPageVar('arr_values')``` which is A progress, now checking where the actual data is not pushed to the window array.

Comment: Events are not serializable. You need to push only the individual properties that you want.

Comment: @wOxxOm Can't thank you enough, It actually works You rock....